# Hadoop for web application

Tags: database, web-applications, hadoop

I am beginner in using Hadoop. I just wanted to know whether I can use Hadoop as backend in web application instead of using relation database?

Comment: Hadoop isn't a DB, it's a Map/Reduce framework. Maybe you mean HBase?

Comment: It's HDFS+MapReduce. So, it can be used as a backend, but not for real time applications.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot compare Hadoop with RDBMS on the first place, as it is not a database. It just provides you a FileSystem(HDFS) which like any other FS lacks the ability of random read/write. If you really want to have a distributed backend for your web app, you could make use of something like HBase on top of Hadoop. It'll provide you real-time, random read/write capabilities. And, yes most importantly, Hadoop is best suited for batch processing kinda stuff, as @Abhinav has already said.

Answer (score 0):

In 1 line...**NO**...hadoop is meant for batch processing of large data....

Comment: Thanks all for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "No, You shouldn't" but as someone pointed out above that isnt the whole answer.

Hadoop is not a drop in replacement for an RDBMS - it is both a distributed file store and distributed compute mechanism. Both of these things do not help a website by themselves.

Now it is possible that you have tonnes of "Big Data" which you have in Hadoop which could be made available through HBase if it is essentially a "Key/Value" lookup. BUT there are quite a few key value stores which may be more suitable.

If you still need SQL there are tools like Hive or Impala and others that give you SQL-like behaviour. With Hive the drawback is that it uses MapReduce - which means each query might take over a minute!!! OK for huge reports, but not ok for anything else. Impala is supposed to speed that up, but I don't have practical experience of that.

Comment: As per my experience, Hive is not good for real time stuff and Impala is bad for heavy data operations like Joins etc as it uses MPP and is quite memory intensive. So, if you have lots of data you might run out of memory. Moreover he intends to access the backend through web service and not directly by writing SQL queries.